# question regarding a transformer

Tags: transformer

I'm building a 150 Hz sine wave circuit using op amp 741, capacitors and resistors. The amplitude of the output would be a bit less than 5 Vrms. Now I want to connect the circuit output to electro optic[EO] crystal so it would operate, the crystal (works as a phase shift and also as an isolator so current can be neglible) works at 600 Vrms.

I'm looking for a small transformer that can work @150 Hz and step up 5 Vrms to 600 Vrms,

Is that a feasible requirement? How can i implement it? I look all over for transformers that will do the job but no luck.

Comment: "small transformer" and "5Hz" are pretty much opposed to each other, and 120:1 implies an impedance transformation of 14400:1 which is also problematic. Find another approach. Also tell us the required current for the crystal, or the load impedance it presents.

Comment: the current is not an issue because the crystal is an isolator(used for a phase shift), what the impedance requirments i should look for ? i guess the primary should be much higher than secondary but whats the values? or what can i conclode about a transformer from its impedance?

Comment: and whats 'isolation voltage' in a transformer means?

Comment: Answer questions to get answers - What is the impedance of the xtal at 5 Hz and what RMS voltage is needed across it?

Comment: IMO the equivalnt transformer is 50Hz 50V/6kV

Comment: 5 Hz or 150 Hz? Some audio line drive transformers with low impedance speaker outputs may come close. | A current transformer MAY work but you' need to remove any clamping components from the HV side and the voltage rating is likely to be too low. | You could use the secondary of any transformer rated at 600V and wind a new primary. This wou;ld probably require under 100 turns in many cases. | The 741 is VERY obsolete. Use an LM324 (which is only obsolete) or something newer.

Answer (score 2):

You could consider an oil burner ignition transformer, such as [these](http://www.allanson.com/environmental-electrics/products/transformers/production-transformers), which cost around $40 and are not small. They have a 10kV output winding with center grounded, (the latter which may or may not be acceptable for your application).

[image]

For 600VAC out, the required input voltage would be 7.2V RMS (about 10V peak) and they should work okay at 5Hz with up to  800VAC+ out.

The usual approach in this frequency range would be to create some high voltage rails (+/- somewhat more than your peak output voltage requirement) and use a high voltage DC-coupled amplifier to drive the crystal.

In either case, crystal capacitance could cause issues with amplifier stability. The transformer will multiply the output capacitance by about 7000:1 (square of the turns ratio).

Comment: Any idea of the primary inductance on these? As they are intended for 50/60Hz use I've a feeling it'll be uncomfortably low, increasing the drive current, but at only 7Vrms at least they shouldn't saturate...

Comment: @BrianDrummond No. They're intended for intermittent use so they may not follow the same rules of thumb as transformers designed for continuous operation.